# bitmap.save subfolder with string value

Tags: c#, winforms

**My code**

```
string userid;
string userimageid;

bitmap.save(@"C:\temper\temp\"+userid+"\"+userimageid+".jpg");
```

get build error! why can´t I create subfolder with string value name and insert image? still cant insert to that crated folder as name userid.

Comment: You should share *which* build error you're getting.

Comment: You should list your error. My guess is you didn't escape the backslash in "\".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you must create first the folder and then save the bitmap:

```
string folderName = @"C:\temper\temp\"+userid;
if (!Directory.Exists(folderName) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
}
bitmap.save(folderName + "\\userimage.jpg");  //your original concatenation had an error
```

Comment: "\\userimage.jpg" this one is my problem. I want insert into created subfolder... only one step to solved.

Comment: He won't get build error if the folder doesn't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
string folderName = @"C:\temper\temp\"+userid;
if (!Directory.Exists(folderName) {
Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
}
bitmap.save(folderName + "\\" +userimage+ ".jpg"); `Create first folder and save Thanks Mnieto`
```